# Image tag within javascript - rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have a line of javascript within my view in my rails app:

```
<script>

$(this).find("img").attr("src", "/assets/img5.png"); 

</script>
```

I have the image path hard coded as you can see. This is working fine locally, but is not working well on production because i'm serving the assets through a cdn.

How do I include an image tag without messing up the javascript?

Comment: Whats the path of the asset on the CDN?

Comment: I'd like to completely avoid hard coding it.

Comment: Well yeah, but the answer depends on how the CDN path is structured.

Comment: Oh sorry! cdn.example.com/assets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around a bit, I found something that works:

```
<script>

$(this).find("img").attr("src", '<%= asset_path 'img5.png' %>'); 

</script>
```

Looks like asset_path gets the job done.

Comment: yea, looks like it works. asset_path has the host coming from config file which automatically appends the cdn path.

Comment: Yup! Works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would be using soemthing like

```
jQuery('img[src*="signup_arrow.png"]')
```

without changing much of the current code. Here `src*` indicates that "signup_arrow.png" can be a substring of the image src.

Typically CDN urls would be http://cdn.example.com/signup_arrow.png?13304 to using the selector to find the given image name as substring helps.

Comment: can you paste the error response and code you tried, it helps debug